# How can I save a GUID correctly as a string?

Tags: vba, ms-access, guid

I have GUIDs saved in a SQL server table which is linked to a MS-Access database (Data Type in Access: "Replication ID").

In the forms I see the GUID like this: {CFFACB63-5EB1-43B2-BCCB-ACF6B226B4F4}

Now I want to use the GUID in code it only shows as "????????"

```
Dim strGuid As String
strGuid = CStr(Me.TransGUID)
Debug.Print " strGuid: '" & strGuid & "'"
Debug.Print " Len(strGuid): " & Len(strGuid) & ""
```

shows: strGuid: '????????', Len(strGuid): 8

I used GUIDs in code before and never had any problems and I see this the first time. I am confused what is happening here. How can I save the GUID the way it is and why does it not save it in the way it should? Any ideas?

The GUID shows as strange characters like Chinese if I show the saved string in a form field.

[image: GUID shown in a form]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access has a built-in function to convert GUIDs to strings.

```
Dim strGuid As String
strGuid = StringFromGUID(Me.TransGUID)
Debug.Print " strGuid: '" & strGuid & "'"
```

While you can use native WinAPI functions to convert it, there's no need for that.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Was this always like this? I thought I did above before and it worked before. But maybe I only received the GUID from SQL queries in VBA and I saved them as text.

Comment: I haven't used Access for that long, but if the GUIDs are properly encoded you always need to cast it this way afaik

Answer (score 1):

GUID is a 16 binary bytes data type and you have to convert it to human readable string to display. You can use API functions for this, see, for instance, [here](http://www.trigeminal.com/code/guids.bas).